# Form not showing in administration menu in Drupal6

Tags: routes, forms

I'm trying to create a simple form with a textfield in the administration panel but I get the message "You do not have any administrative items"

Here is the code inside my ptm_autocomplete.module:

```
function ptm_autocomplete_menu() {                                              
  $items['admin/prestum/autocomplete'] = array(                                 
    'title' => 'Autocomplete',                                                  
    'description' => 'Autocomplete',                                            
    'page_callback' => 'drupal_get_form',                                       
    'page arguments' => array('ptm_autocomplete_form', array(), array()),       
    'access arguments' => array('access administration pages'),                 
  );                                                                            

  return $items;                                                                
}                                                                               

function ptm_autocomplete_form(&$form_state, $unused, $form_values) {           
  $form = array();                                                              

  $form['name'] = array(                                                        
    '#type' => 'textfield',                                                     
    '#title' => t('Color'),                                                     
    '#description' => t('Color'),                                               
  );                                                                            

  $form['submit'] = array(                                                      
    '#type' => 'submit',                                                        
    '#value' => 'Submit',                                                       
  );                                                                            

  return $form;                                                                 
}
```

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an an underscore (`_`) in `page_callback`. Remove that, clear the caches, and you should be good to go.

```
function ptm_autocomplete_menu() {                                              
  $items['admin/prestum/autocomplete'] = array(                                 
    'title' => 'Autocomplete',                                                  
    'description' => 'Autocomplete',                                            
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',                                       
    'page arguments' => array('ptm_autocomplete_form', array(), array()),       
    'access arguments' => array('access administration pages'),                 
  );                                                                            

  return $items;                                                                
}
```

Also if this is Drupal 7 your form function should have `$form` as the first param:

```
function ptm_autocomplete_form($form, &$form_state, $unused, $form_values) { ...
```

But not for Drupal 6.